# Array to calculate an average

Tags: java

I'm attempting to calculate the average number of entries using an array. The method doesn't execute properly. Any help is appreciated.

```
public static double calculateAverage (double[] Array) {
    int person= 0;
    int total= 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < person.length; i++)
{
    total += avgCustomer[i];
}
    double avgPerson = total/ person.length;
    return avgPerson;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden" and "visible"?

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"?

Comment: So your question is "Why do I get a compiler error when I remove the declaration of a variable?"

Comment: I'm guessing that `bfpArray` and `avgCustomer` are not doing what is expected, since they are initialized to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

At least one part of the issue is this:

```
int customer = 0;
...
double[] bfpArray = new double[customer];
int[] avgCustomer = new int[customer];

System.out.print("Please enter the number of customers: ");
customer = input.nextInt();
```

As this current code will create the arrays `bfpArray` and `avgCustomer` to have a length of 0.

Moving the array initialization until after the number of customers has been collected (though it would be good to ensure that the entry is valid) would help:

```
System.out.print("Please enter the number of customers: ");
customer = input.nextInt();

double[] bfpArray = new double[customer];
int[] avgCustomer = new int[customer];
```

Then, as @shikai ng noted, you will need to adjust your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < customer; i++) {
```

as Java arrays are 0 based.

Comment: @smokey, look closely at the code for `calculateAverage`. Does it, perhaps, appear to have the same deficiency in initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You are having an array out of bound exception. just make sure you start ur for loop with i = 0 not i = 1

```
    for (i = 0; i <= customer; i++) {
    ......}
```

and initialize bfparray only after getting the number of customers